# My fonts are sometimes displaying as Chinese/Japanese?

Tags: font

I am getting a problem with fonts on my machine sometimes showing as Chinese/Japanese characters (I'm not sure which).

This happens in many apps, although the ones where it is easily reproducable include Pages '09 (Mac App Store version):

[image]

And in the "Type your password to confirm" dialogue box when installing applications:

[image]

I am running OS X 10.7.2 on a 27-inch, Mid 2011 iMac. I do not use any "Font management" apps although I've installed a few fonts from Font Squirrel in the past.

(I could not embed the images because I have no reputation on this site).

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper localization settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this kind of problem can be solved by going to system preferences/language & text/language and using the Edit button to uncheck the box for Japanese,  and then restarting.